# Предсказать максимально близкое число

Tags: алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

Задана некоторая последовательность чисел, требуется предсказать следующее число которое будет в этой последовательности (точнее максимально близкое число, которое вероятнее всего выпадет).

Например, если последовательность такая: `3, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 5, 5, 6, 3, 7` то, скорее всего (на мой взгляд), можно взять среднее арифмитическое, для предсказания следующего числа.

Но может быть и такая последовательность, `7, 7, 10 34, 5, 18, 5, 77, 8, 24, 16, 1400, 900, 1100` то среди такой последовательности брать среднее не правильно. 
Т.к. по последовательности видно, что чаще всего выпадают числа с диапазоном до 100, и скорее всего с большей вероятностью следующее число будет ближе к среднему значению среди подпоследовательности `7, 7, 10 34, 5, 18, 5, 77, 8, 24, 16`

подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть алгоритмы решения подобных задач, как это называется ?

Comment: В данной формулировке это не более чем попытка предсказать следующее число, которое выдаст генератор случайных чисел. Предсказывать можно лишь в случае, когда за этой последовательностью скрывается некий неслучайный процесс, который может быть хотя бы теоретически описан математически (пусть и каким-то многоэтажным безобразием). Только на основе знаний или хотя бы предположений о типе этого описания можно делать какие-то предсказания.

Comment: *Но может быть и такая последовательность, 7, 7, 10 34, 5, 18, 5, 77, 8, 24, 16, 1400, 900, 1100 то среди такой последовательности брать среднее не правильно.* Угу... может же существовать такая версия: "ГСЧ, работающий в диапазоне целых чисел от 1 до 1500, выдал последовательность 7, 7, 10 34, 5, 18, 5, 77, 8, 24, 16, 1400, 900, 1100, предскажите следующее число". И как на фоне этого смотрится Ваше *скорее всего с большей вероятностью следующее число будет ближе к среднему значению среди подпоследовательности 7, 7, 10 34, 5, 18, 5, 77, 8, 24, 16*?

Comment: Вообще задача очень похожа на https://www.kaggle.com/c/integer-sequence-learning - Обучение целочисленной последовательности с kaggle. Могу лишь посоветовать алгоритмы, которые могут помочь предсказать следующее число в последовательности.Самые простые: взвешенное среднее, скользящее среднее. Поинтереснее алгоритмы: экспоненциальное сглаживание (двойное, тройное). Подробнее здесь https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/327242/ - временные ряды

Comment: @Akina это небольшая задача, которая возникла при решении задач  по анализу данных.

Задача в том, чтобы предсказать объем продаж заданной игры. Для этого есть база игр, со всеми параметрами игры (категория игры, тип, автор, объем продаж и т.д.).
Для предсказания объема продаж заданной игры - `X`, я нашел максимально похожий набор игр из базы (похожий по всем характеристикам, кроме названия и объема продаж).

Например я нашел в базе `N` таких игр, теперь мне нужно на основе этих данных предсказать объем продаж для игры `X`.

Comment: Описанная мной последовательность чисел, это и есть объем продаж, на основе которых мне надо предсказать для игры `X`. Других данных для анализа нету.

Comment: Ну так это же ж совсем другое дело... У вас есть некой процесс, который имеет (в первом приближении) как минимум периодическую составляющую (зависимость от дня недели, сезона и пр.), непериодическую (постепенное падение интереса), разовую (акция, выход аналога или новой версии) и случайную, и каждая со своим весовым коэффициентом. Обработка имеющихся данных позволит получить хоть какие-то оценки для этих коэффициентов, по крайней мере по отношению друг к другу (степень влияния тех или иных процессов), имеющаяся последовательность - подрихтовать их. И можно экстраполировать.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве первого приближения обычно предлагается взять медиану - она поустойчивей, чем среднее арифметическое, что как раз хорошо подойдет ко второму примеру.

Ну и как раз мерой того, что во временном ряду есть выбросы будет большое отличие среднего от медианы.

Answer (score 1):

Пока не появился комментарий про "*объем продаж заданной игры*" можно было с уверенностью сказать, что метод решения вашей задачи следует искать среди методов анализа временных рядов. Как тут и предлагали.

Однако, оговорка, что "*есть база игр, со всеми параметрами игры (категория игры, тип, автор, объем продаж и т.д.). Для предсказания объема продаж заданной игры - X"* серьезно меняет суть вопроса. В такой постановке непонятно, что значит в вашем понимании "последовательность"?  Этот термин обычно применяют тогда, когда вы исследуете изменение значений одного и того-же параметра во времени. А в вашей "базе игр" такого параметра ("момент времени") нет, по крайней мере вы его (почему-то) не указали.

Таким образом, по вашему описанию, у вас есть таблица из N строк (каждая строка - игра) и каким-то числом столбцов (категория игры, тип, автор, объем продаж и т.д.). Каждая клетка таблице - это значение определенного параметра для одной из игр. По этой таблице вам надо построить  зависимость (модель), используя которую в дальнейшем вы будете  для некоторой новой игры ПРЕДСКАЗЫВАТЬ значение параметра "объем продаж" по известным  значениям остальных параметров.

Если бы все параметры были количественными, это приводило бы к типичной задаче многомерной регрессии.  Однако у вас (все или некоторые) параметры - номинальные. Таким образом вы приходите к задаче классификации, скорее всего к т.н.  kNN-методу (методу ближайших соседей) в какой-то из его модификаций.

Если же мое понимание того, что вы пытаетесь сделать не соответствует вашей задачи - уточните ее. И тогда, возможно, метод решения придется искать какой-то другой.